# Cannot install MiKTex 2.9 on Windows 10 (64-bit)

Tags: miktex, windows

I believe this is a frequently asked question, but I have been attempting to install MikTex 2.9 on my PC for over a week, read all previous threads pertaining to this issue, shut down all anti-virus software, did not rename,..., but I could not even ascertain if the MikTex has actually installed on my machine.

Following one of the suggestions from [this thread][1], I "right clicked" MikTex exe file on my Downloads folder and "run as administrator" as I have no way to avoid the `exitCode="1"` error at the end. Finally the latest version `6643` seems to have installed, but when I compiled with my `Winedt`, the `pdflatex` quickly stopped, saying pdflatex.exe did not succeed and... it was executed with the `6630` version!

Does this imply the latest version `6643` was not installed at all? Could anyone lend a helping hand on this?

I feel frustrated after upgrading to Windows 10 after which I was unable to run all stand-alone LaTeX editors on it.

FYI, if I did not use the "right click" --> "run as administrator" trick then this is error message I got from log file

```
 initializing setup service...
 starting installer...
 Loading package database...
 starting package maintenance...
 installation directory: "C:\Users\hktse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9"
 package repository: C:\Users\hktse\AppData\Local\Temp\mik6527
 visiting repository C:\Users\hktse\AppData\Local\Temp\mik6527...
 repository type: local package repository
 loading lightweight database...
 lightweight database digest: 988a4b83024c02f8f95fdf68e1a944bb
 going to install 10673 file(s) (215 package(s))
 extracting files from ae.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from amscls.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from amsfonts.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from amsmath.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from asymptote.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from avantgar.cab...
 extracting files from babel.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from babel-english.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from babel-french.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from babel-german.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from babel-spanish.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from bibtex.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from bibtex8bit.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from bibtex8bit-polish.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from bidi.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from bookman.cab...
 extracting files from carlisle.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from cbcoptic.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from chktex.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from cm.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from courier.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from cweb.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from cyrillic.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from dehyph.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from dehyph-exptl.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from dvipdfmx.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from dvips.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from ec.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from elhyphen.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from enctex.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from etex.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from etex-pkg.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from euenc.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from eurosym.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from float.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from fontconfig.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from fontname.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from fontspec.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from geometry.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from ghostscript.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from graphics.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from graphics-cfg.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from graphics-def.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from gsftopk.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from helvetic.cab...
 extracting files from hyperref.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from hyph-utf8.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from ifxetex.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from jknappen.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from knuth-lib.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from knuth-local.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from latex-fonts.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from lm.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from ltxbase.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from ltxmisc.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from lua-alt-getopt.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from luainputenc.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from lualibs.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from luamplib.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from luaotfload.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from luatexbase.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from luatextra.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from makeindex.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from metafont.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from metapost.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from mflogo.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from mflogo-font.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from mfware.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-arctrl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-asymptote-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-autosp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-axohelp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-bibarts-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-biber-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-bibtex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-bibtex8bit-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-bzip2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-cairo-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-chktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-cjkutils-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-config-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-console-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-curl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-cweb-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-devnag-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-dict-english.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-dict-french.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-dict-german.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-doc-2.9.tar.lzma...
 extracting files from miktex-dvicopy-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipng-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvisvgm-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-epstopdf-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-etex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-expat-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-findtexmf-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fonts-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-freetype2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fribidixetex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gd-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ghostscript-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-graphite2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gregorio-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gsf2pk-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-harfbuzz-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-hunspell-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-icu-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-int-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-jpeg-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-kpathsea-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lacheck-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-latex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-libressl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-log4cxx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lua52-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lua53-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-luatex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-luatex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lzma-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-m-tx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-makeindex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-md5-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metafont.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metafont-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metapost.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metapost-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mfware-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-misc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mkfntmap-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mo-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mpfr-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mpmcli-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mspack-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mthelp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mtprint-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-omega.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-omega-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pixman-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pmx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-png-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-poppler-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-popt-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-posix-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-potrace-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ps2pk-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-psutils-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-qt5-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-runtime-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tdsutil-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-teckit-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex2xindy-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex4ht.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex4ht-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texify-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texinfo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texware-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texworks-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ttf2pk2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ucrt-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-uriparser-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-vc140-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-web-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xetex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xindy-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-yap-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zip-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zlib-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zzip-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from multirow.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ncntrsbk.cab...
extracting files from oberdiek.tar.lzma...
extracting files from palatino.cab...
extracting files from pdftex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from plain.tar.lzma...
extracting files from polyglossia.tar.lzma...
extracting files from poppler.tar.lzma...
extracting files from pslatex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from psnfss.cab...
extracting files from pstricks.tar.lzma...
extracting files from psutils.tar.lzma...
extracting files from rsfs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ruhyphen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from tetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from tex-ini-files.tar.lzma...
extracting files from texinfo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from thumbpdf.tar.lzma...
extracting files from times.cab...
extracting files from tools.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ttf2pk.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ukrhyph.tar.lzma...
extracting files from unicode-data.tar.lzma...
extracting files from utopia.cab...
extracting files from xetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xgreek.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xindy.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xkeyval.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xltxtra.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xunicode.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xypic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from zapfchan.cab...
extracting files from zapfding.cab...
extracting files from zerohyph.tar.lzma...
updating package definition directory ("C:\Users\hktse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tpm\packages")...
installed 3281 package definition files
visiting repository C:\Users\hktse\AppData\Local\Temp\mik6527...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
initexmf "--user-install=C:\Users\hktse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9" "--common-install=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9" --set-config-value=[Core]SharedSetup=0 "--log-file=C:\Users\hktse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --disable-installer --verbose:
Registering root directories...
initexmf --rmfndb "--log-file=C:\Users\hktse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --disable-installer --verbose:
Removing fndb (C:\Users\hktse\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
Removing fndb (C:\Users\hktse\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
Removing fndb (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/hktse/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
  source line: 166
  message: The executed process did not succeed.
  info: fileName="C:\Users\hktse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX   2.9\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1"
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This seems to mean the latest version was installed in a different directory from the previous version, which was not uninstalled. What I would gdo if I were: I'd uninstall MiKTeX (all installed versions) with an uninstaller (like Revo Uninstaller) which scans the system afterwards, cleanse the registry, &c., and re-install the latest version.

Comment: Strangely, when I used Windows 10's built-in unstaller to unstall MikTex 2.9, it says it cannot find MikTex 2.9 (but it was indeed listed on my downloaded Apps).

Comment: Strange… But  I don't know Windows 10 (I preferred to stay under Windows 7…)

Comment: It appears that the downloaded file was stored in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9`, but still, Windows says it could not find the file so there is no way for it to uninstall it...

Comment: This is a quite useless comment, I admit, but it might be the last straw for you to switch. Linux has much better support for many things, including TeX. There, you just install TeX Live from your package manager and that's it.

Comment: Or MiKTeX for Linux…

Comment: Why didn't download in the…Downloads directory?

Comment: I did put it in downloads directory, and then double clicked the exe file to complete the download process, but it never worked, always ended up with error message.
Also, it one reads my log file (displayed in the question thread above), the installation file was stored in `Local\Programs` but the package repository was in `Local\Temp`, is this normal?

Comment: I advise you to try the portable install.

Comment: I've also tried chocolatey to install MikTex on command prompt, but, again, Windows 10 cannot recognize it.

Comment: And does an uninstaller  (other than  the Windows 10 one) find where it is?

Comment: Yes, they can "find" it but after I select MikTex 2.9 as the file to be uninstalled, it says there is no such file....... (sorry I have no idea what I am talking about because I am also very confused...)

Comment: Try  to find with Windows explorer the location of the MiKTeX 2.9 directory. In `MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\internal` , you'll find `uninstall.exe` and `uninstall_admin.exe`. What happens if you launch them?

Comment: The problem is MikTex 2.9 isn't anywhere in any folders (because I believe I have deleted it), it only appears in Settings --> System --> Apps and Features but if I click uninstall, Windows says this program doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe it's a hidden directory?

Comment: The whole thing is just unfathomable, I regretted for having upgraded to Windows 10...

Comment: I have windows 10 and miktex and it works fine. I did install it in my user account in single user mode without any admin rights. But after all your tries it is quite impossible to know what it going on on your machine.

Comment: I've installed it on three different win10 machines, two of which were not my own, and it works fine. Don't be dissuated by the two softwares. I believe they can be made to work. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot comment on the errors that you are receiving, I would suggest that you try to install the portable version of Miktex.

[Miktex Portable](https://miktex.org/portable)

You can even install it on a flash-drive and use that installation on any MS-Windows machine.

The idea of the "Portable apps" is to contain all the installation files in one location and not to spread them across the system.

Although I would second Oleg's comment about Linux, I am actually quite happy with Miktex.

Comment: This works but is kinda cumbersome. I took my laptop to our department's IT guy, it took him a while to figure out what's going on (but did not supply me with an answer though), I was finally able to re-install MikTex 2.9 on my Windows 10 machine.